# Function to generate alpha numeric string

Tags: string, oracle, function

I was asked to create a function which goes round Robin through the alphabet A-Z (caps only) and concatenate it with the decimal part of a TIMESTAMP. This function should ALWAYS generate a unique string.

Can the function use something like not EXISTS before generating the value therefore guaranteeing uniqueness? I would like to keep the alpha part of the string and generate a new fractional part of the TIMESTAMP. Basically, retry logic in the function?

The end result should generate a sample output similar to this

A432635
B227541
C986435
…
…
Z885525  back around to A
A543422
B008545

I am out of my league and was hoping someone can help me out. My attempt below is incorrect as it is increasing the size of the alpha part of the string once I pass 'Z'.

```
SELECT       RPAD (SUBSTR ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                          ,DECODE (MOD ( ROWNUM, 26), 0, 26, MOD ( ROWNUM, 26))
                          ,1)
                  ,FLOOR ( (ROWNUM - 1) / 26) + 1
                  ,SUBSTR ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
                          ,DECODE (MOD ( ROWNUM, 26), 0, 26, MOD ( ROWNUM, 26))
                          ,1))
      FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY   LEVEL <= 130;
```

Comment: If it is function, why `CONNECT BY   LEVEL <= 130;` and not simple loop? Also against what is expected to test uniqueness of this value? Clarify you setup and intentions on hpw it would be used.

Comment: @markalex the CONNECT by was just to show what I tried. The application will call the function and return a 7 character string. This value is equivalent to employee_id. I realize I will need a mechanism to know what the last alpha character that was used. But I haven't gotten that far yet. Also, I would like an all Oracle software that is why I suggested perhaps the not EXISTS or something similar

Comment: All the homegrown solutions for sequence generation should be thoroughly tested to work in concurrency, to handle rollbacks, application crash etc. While you  suspect that timestamp is enough to support uniqueness, why do you expect a regular sequence to generate too large numbers? They should not be larger than timestamps or timestamps will overlap with each other (including letters). You may use a general sequence and convert some part of the value to base 36 (a-z + 0-9) and apply some hash function to obfuscate the original value instead of custom sequence implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't explain *why* you want to do that. Because, if it is about uniqueness, there are way simpler ways to do it than create your own unique string which is about to fail sooner or later, and - to detect it - you have to do some programming.

Therefore, I'd suggest you to:

- use identity column and let Oracle handle it itself
- or, use a sequence (either manually, or create a trigger which will handle it)
- if it has to look as you said (letter + timestamp), use both date and time component as it'll make uniqueness violation less likely to happen (unless you're working with many values at a time, and Oracle is really fast so you get the same timestamp)

If nothing of above is acceptable, then here's one option you can use; there's a table that contains previously created unique strings. Function is an autonomous transaction so that it could insert & commit unique strings; it also checks whether newly created strings exists - not by potentially slow select, but direct insert which will fail on unique index. In that case, go get another value.

```
SQL> create table robin
  2    (id        number generated always as identity,
  3     value     varchar2(7),
  4     --
  5     constraint pk_robin primary key (id),
  6     constraint uk_robin unique (value)
  7    );

Table created.

SQL> -- insert the 1st row manually, to simplify function's code
SQL> insert into robin (value) values ('A' || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24miss'));

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_robin
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  5    l_letter   varchar2(1);  -- first character in that "unique string"
  6    retval     varchar2(7);  -- return value
  7  begin
  8    loop
  9    begin
 10      -- get first character
 11      select substr(value, 1, 1)
 12        into l_letter
 13        from robin
 14        order by id desc
 15        fetch first 1 rows only;
 16      -- if 1st character is Z, start a new one with A; else, take letter that
 17      -- follows L_LETTER
 18      retval := case when l_letter = 'Z' then 'A'
 19                     else chr(ascii(l_letter) + 1)
 20                end || to_char(sysdate, 'hh24miss');
 21      -- insert newly created value into the table. If insert succeds, return
 22      insert into robin (value) values (retval);
 23      commit;
 24      return retval;
 25    exception
 26      -- insert failed (because uniqueness was violated); go get another value
 27      when dup_val_on_index then
 28        null;
 29    end;
 30    end loop;
 31  end;
 32  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_value varchar2(7);
  3  begin
  4    for i in 1 .. 30 loop
  5      l_value := f_robin;
  6    end loop;
  7  end;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from robin order by id;

        ID VALUE
---------- -------
         1 A213624
         2 B213624
         3 C213624
         4 D213624
         5 E213624
         6 F213624
         7 G213624
         8 H213624
         9 I213624
        10 J213624
        11 K213624
<snip>
        25 Y213624
        26 Z213624
       304 A213625
       305 B213625
       306 C213625
       307 D213625
       308 E213625

31 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for your help and expertise. The value generated is a customer_id, which users will provide when logging in. I was envisioning using the fractional part of the TIMESTAMP to make it harder for others to hack. For example, I don't want user A111111 to be able to try B111111 and guess the login. I thought the fractional part of the TIMESTAMP would make that more difficult to hack? That is why I didn't want a sequence or identity column. I also didn't want some huge string either as it would make it difficult for users to remember. Hope I clarified my request.

Answer (score 2):

> I was asked to create a function which goes round Robin through the alphabet A-Z (caps only) and concatenate it with the decimal part of a TIMESTAMP.

You can write the function as:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name;

CREATE FUNCTION alphanum_string RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN CHR(MOD(sequence_name.NEXTVAL - 1, 26) + 65)
      || TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'FF6');
END;
/
```

> This function should ALWAYS generate a unique string.

Don't use your idea for a function then as it will eventually produce repeating values.

Either just use a sequence:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name;

CREATE FUNCTION get_sequence_value RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN sequence_name.NEXTVAL;
END;
/
```

or use a GUID:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION get_guid_string RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN SYS_GUID();
END;
/
```

Although, in both cases, you do not need a function and can directly use `sequence_name.NEXTVAL` or `CAST(SYS_GUID() AS VARCHAR2)`.

If you did want a random UUID then you can use Java within the database (if it is enabled):

```sql
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED JavaUUID AS
public class JavaUUID {
  public static String generate(){
    return java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase();
  }
}
/

CREATE FUNCTION UUID RETURN VARCHAR2
  AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'JavaUUID.generate() return java.lang.String';
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT sequence_name.NEXTVAL AS seq,
       CAST(SYS_GUID() AS VARCHAR2(32)) AS guid,
       UUID() as uuid
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Outputs:

| SEQ | GUID | UUID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | F966F1759FD0956EE053182BA8C0A4A5 | F16B2AF4-E5ED-4E13-932F-1F29CA3008CC |
| 2 | F966F1759FD1956EE053182BA8C0A4A5 | 329DF39D-3FB8-4AEF-BF63-46BA51F7709D |
| 3 | F966F1759FD2956EE053182BA8C0A4A5 | E41DA8EB-2F1B-4488-8D83-0A6D8778C79B |
| 4 | F966F1759FD3956EE053182BA8C0A4A5 | CCD51797-7FF4-46A1-9AB4-1FBD9DCED447 |
| 5 | F966F1759FD4956EE053182BA8C0A4A5 | 73D8C9C9-2BE3-471E-8279-A8A756181B77 |
| 6 | F966F1759FD5956EE053182BA8C0A4A5 | 724B1CAC-99BF-4884-8640-0514D5A15D5C |
| 7 | F966F1759FD6956EE053182BA8C0A4A5 | FBE3B326-4544-4A24-A302-00BD360A52AB |
| 8 | F966F1759FD7956EE053182BA8C0A4A5 | CE8FCB97-34D3-455B-B628-2DB90951AC7C |
| 9 | F966F1759FD8956EE053182BA8C0A4A5 | 0464268C-9119-4F98-A603-BAA3088FB946 |
| 10 | F966F1759FD9956EE053182BA8C0A4A5 | 811A5197-1C12-4EC1-8704-DB15CBE7C254 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XHayjZhp)

Comment: @MTO thanks for your help and expertise. As I mentioned in my response to Littlefoot I dont want a sequence or GUID as the VALUES would get to large and make it difficult for users to remember. Your first option reply with the fractional TIMESTAMP is almost there but as I mentioned I need to guarantee the string generated is unique, if not, try again before I return to the caller. I will fumble through trying to combine yours and Littlefoot solution into something that I can use. Thank you very much